Musty/wet soil/slight sour/chemical? smell on first floor in bathrooms and some areas where floor meets the ground
The smell is really hard to describe as you can see from my title. It's not on the whole floor and it comes and goes - sometimes really strong and sometimes none at all. There's no obvious pattern as to when (tried tracking different times of day, weather, hvac usage, etc.). It's not a p-trap issue and it's not a sewage smell (confirmed by plumber). In two bathrooms, I can sort of smell it near the shower drain and where the toilet meets the ground but it's not super strong as one might suspect. In the hallway there are similar smells in some areas where there are gaps between the baseboard and ground, but again not super strong. I have called in 3 plumbers to try and understand what could be the issue and one thinks it was maybe the type of (wrong kind of) glue used to seal the shower drain/toilet. We've tried sealing the shower drain/toilet with plastic/tape but it doesn't seem to be working and it doesn't explain the other areas unless the glue was used in the hallways too which seems unlikely.
I don't even know who to call anymore. Mold specialists like Servpro say they can't track down the source, they need to know where a problem is and then can address it. Not sure if it's mold - humidity levels seem ok.
I don't know what it is, but I'm starting to get nervous as I have young kids. Any ideas on what it might be and more importantly - who to call to help figure it out?

formadelhyde smell from decomposiong engineered floor panels (ply chipboard, osb etc?)  slab floor? raised floor?

Opinion not answer: if you're worried about indoor air quality and you don't have a HRV or ERV with filtration installed, time to get one. There's so many unknowns about what we put in our houses that failing to ventilate exposes you to, many of which we can't smell.
